# String Splitting whenever there is a space and next character is a numeral

Tags: c#

I want to split a string whenever there is space and next character is numeral.
For example input string:

```
Golden State 97   Indiana 108 (FINAL)
```

It should be splitted as:

```
string[0]:Golden State
string[1]:97
string[2]:Indiana
string[3]:108
string[4]:FINAL
```

Please help me out of this.
Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it split as "Golden State", "87 Indiana", and "108 (FINAL)"?

Comment: regex is the way to go here. what have you tried?  Also last piece misses `()` symbols - should special characters be avoided?

Comment: There are probably easier ways with regular expressions but you could split it on space character and then append them back together depending on if you can parse the index to an int or not.

Comment: If you make "Golden State", "Golden_State", you can simply split at every space. Then afterwards just replace "_" with " ".

Comment: hint: take a look at the code example on [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx). It's very close to doing exactly what you need.

Comment: I tried Regex with different combinations but neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the regular expression

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(.*) (\d+) (.*) (\d+) \((.*)\)$");
```

then you can get your values as

```
var m = regex.Match("Golden State 97 Indiana 108 (FINAL)");
if (m.Success)
{
    var string0 = m.Groups[1].Value; // Golden State
    var string1 = m.Groups[2].Value; // 97
    var string2 = m.Groups[3].Value; // Indiana
    var string3 = m.Groups[4].Value; // 108
    var string4 = m.Groups[5].Value; // FINAL
}
```

(as long as none of the team names have any groups of digits in!)

You *could* do this via splitting, but there's no need.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Here what if my input is varying because i am feching data through feeds. But Format is same

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a regular expression to parse the string.

Here is one I've quickly created

"^([a-zA-Z\s]+) (\d+) ([a-zA-Z\s]+) (\d+) (.+)$"

This will match the various parts assuming it is always in the shape you've described above.

Read up about the RegEx class on MSDN. The parts of my RegEx in brackets are called groups. Once you've matched the string against the RegEx, you can access the Groups and each group will contain  a part of the string e.g. "Golden State".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution with regular expressions. This is a bit more generic than the other solutions, because the input format is not fixed.

```
var input = "Golden State 97 Indiana 108 (FINAL)";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?:[a-z][a-z ]*)?[a-z]|\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var values = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```